# Python Recursive Call

Tags: python, recursion

I want to run This code But it gives This Error: 
if n == 0:
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

```
    def gcd(n, m):
    if n == 0:
        return m
    else:
        return gcd(n, m % n)


print(gcd(10, 50))
```

Anyone Knows Why ?

Comment: you never decrease `n` (the first argument); therefore the condition `n == 0` will never hold.

Comment: You're never changing the value of n... When would it be 0?

Comment: Thanks! I must change the place of m and n in def.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do the second return you are actually saying `n = n` and `m = m % n` for the next iteration. You are effectively changing the value of `m` but never the one of `n` so it never gets to 0. Your function is never getting to the exit condition of `n = 0`.

Answer (score -1):

To calculate GCD you need to account for both numbers. By checking only `n` for termination condition and yet mutating only `m`, you keep `n` the same indefinitely in all your recursions, never reaching the termination condition.

You should use the lesser of the two numbers as the divider and pass the remainder to the other number in the next recursion.

```
def gcd(n, m):
    if n == 0:
        return m
    if m == 0:
        return n
    if n > m:
        return gcd(n % m, m)
    return gcd(n, m % n)

print(gcd(10, 50))
```

Comment: if you change the place of m and n in my definition it would be right.

Comment: It has more to do with the need to return the different values depending on which of the two numbers is bigger, and which is 0. I've updated my answer accordingly.